# BeautifulSoup.findAll print nothing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have checked the login is 200 in response, but the result print nothing.
This the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file_in = 'D:\OneDrive\Documents\GPIP\Files\scraping\idlinkedin.csv'
dataset = open(file_in, "r")

def login(iemail,ipassword):
    client = requests.Session()

    HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
    LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'

    html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']

    login_information = {
        'session_key': iemail,
        'session_password': ipassword,
        'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
    }

    client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)

    for username in dataset:
        item_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/' + username.strip()
        source_code = client.get(item_url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features='html.parser')
        for item_name in soup.findAll('h1', {'class': 'pv-top-card-section__name inline t-24 t-black t-normal'}):
            print(item_name)

# MAIN
login('theusername','thepassword')
```

This line supposes to print the name's account, unfortunately, the result is nothing.

```
for item_name in soup.findAll('h1', {'class': 'pv-top-card-section__name inline t-24 t-black t-normal'}):
                print(item_name)
```

Comment: Can you post the content that you get in `plain_text`?

Comment: Can you try with lxml parser and use find_all function? that might work. And I have never used findAll function please refer my code once on git hub. https://github.com/simplyshravan/python_learning/blob/master/Freelancer/Web_Scrapy_Project.py

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are doing code on the basis of what you are looking in browser elements (that appears on F12 in chrome browser), not on the basis of what response you are getting in requests.get function. I have faced same problem when I was doing scraping with instagram.com-->(please refer this link on git hub https://github.com/simplyshravan/python_learning/blob/master/Using_beautifulsoup.py).

Always look for what you are receiving, not what it looks like.
So after spending couple of hours below is the code to extract user's information from linkedin.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

file_in = r'D:\OneDrive\Documents\GPIP\Files\scraping\idlinkedin.csv'
dataset = open(file_in, "r")

def login(iemail,ipassword):
    client = requests.Session()

    HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
    LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'

    html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']

    login_information = {
        'session_key': iemail,
        'session_password': ipassword,
        'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
    }

    client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)

    for username in dataset:
        item_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/' + username.strip()
        print(item_url)
        source_code = client.get(item_url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for item_name in soup.find_all('code'):
            if str(item_name).find('firstName') > -1:
                for i in json.loads(item_name.text)['included']:
                    #print(i)
                    if len(i['$deletedFields']) > 0:
                        if i['$type']=='com.linkedin.voyager.identity.shared.MiniProfile':
                            if i["publicIdentifier"]==username.strip():
                                    print(i['firstName']+' '+i['lastName'])
                                    print(i['lastName'])
                                    print(i['occupation'])
                                    break

# MAIN
login('username','password')
```